# SQL Comparing Data from Two Tables

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two tables Route and Booking

```
CREATE TABLE Route (
RouteID numeric(4),
RouteIMG blob,
RDetails varchar2(40),
CONSTRAINT Route_pk PRIMARY KEY (RouteID));
```

And

```
CREATE TABLE Booking (
BookingID numeric(4),
BookingType varchar2(1),
StartTime date,
EndTime date,
Date date,
History varchar2(25),
RouteID numeric(4),
ExaminerID numeric(4),
InstructorID numeric(4),
StudentID numeric(4),
CONSTRAINT Booking_pk PRIMARY KEY (BookingID),
CONSTRAINT Route_fk FOREIGN KEY (RouteID) REFERENCES Route,
CONSTRAINT Student_fk FOREIGN KEY (StudentID) REFERENCES Student);
```

I want to compare `Booking.RouteId` with `Route.RouteId` and return the Id which isn't in the Booking table.

For example,

Route Table contains the Route Id's
0001
0002
0003

and in the Bookings table the routes booked are
0001
0002

How can I complete this comparison and return the value
0003

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `left join` and then you should check the booking_id is null.

```
SELECT r.route_id 
FROM Route r LEFT JOIN Booking b ON r.route_id=b.RouteId
WHERE b.RouteId  is null
```

or you can use:

```
SELECT r.RouteID 
FROM Route r 
WHERE RouteID NOT IN(SELECT b.RouteId FROM Booking b)
```

Comment: The join won't give the correct results because you are joining on the wrong columns. r.routeid = b.routeid

Comment: @tobsey was a little mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
select R.RouteID 
from Route R 
where RouteID not in (select B.RouteId from Booking B)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select route_id from route 
where route_id not in ( select route_id from booking )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    Route.RouteID
FROM
    Route
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT
        NULL
    FROM
        Booking
    WHERE
        Booking.RouteID = Route.RouteID)
```

Most of the other answers should work, but I prefer using `EXISTS`since that's what it's intended for.

Answer (score 0):

You could use set operation

```
 SELECT RouteID  FROM Route
 MINUS
 SELECT RouteId FROM Booking
```